# Scraping base64 image src with python breaks the url

Tags: python

I'm using beautifulSoup to gather the url of a scraping page. I get this same url in the following form:

> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==

However, it shows nothing and I've noticed that the url is not the same as the one embed in the webpage. (for example, there is +1 "=" at the end of the string).

Why exactly is does this happen?

I've tried unescaping the string using `.decode` but obviously `/` is not a escape character like `\`.

Could someone please confirm this to me?

Tyvm :)

Comment: `=` are just padding characters at the end of the `base64` string

Comment: Post your code I think I know the issue.

Comment: @NoahCristino There is not much to be honest. I simply get the code and then run it via beautiful soup like this `soup = BeautifulSoup(code)`. Then I get the 'src' of the image element